# Why is my YouTube playlist (showinfo thumbnails) not visible on Iphone?

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

Here is the playlist embedded on the webpage: http://www.grabtownlife.com/videos.html. It works fine on a desktop browser and you can see the playlist thumbnails at the bottom of the video. When you try to view this page on your Iphone, you don't see the thumbnails. Is there a way to make the thumbnails show up on an Iphone?

Answer (score 0):

There is not at the moment. Once/if support for this sort of thing is added to the HTML5 <video> player then it will appear automatically without you having to do anything different. But full parity with playlist functionality and UI between the desktop Flash player and mobile HTML5 <video> player is ways off.